# PayPal Subscriptions API: retrieving information for a existing billing plan ID using curl

Tags: curl, paypal

The question is about PayPal API via curl: once the plan is created how to recheck later

Following https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/
I'm able to create my token, create a product, create a plan and I get the ID of the plan.

In the response there is

```
'links' => array ( 0 => array ( 'href' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/____PLANID_____',
```

How can I formulate a curl command to retrieve the information of this plan id at a later point?

I tried...

```
$paypalcurl = 'curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans/____PLANID_____ \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer '.paypal_tokenix().'" ';
$plan_result = json_decode(exec($paypalcurl.' 2>&1'),true);

var_dump($plan_result,true);
```

But received no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> curl -v -X POST

Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_get

Use method GET.